# lego digital designer automatically convert in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, nxt, lego

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear sirs,
Hello, could you please help me and tell how can I convert a Lego NXT model that i created in Lego digital designer to gazebo for simulation ?? I really need to know how can I convert my model into gazebo,
thanks
Best regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10362/lego-digital-designer-automatically-convert-in-gazebo/) by [khabar](https://answers.ros.org/users/732/khabar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-06-23**:
Original asker was khabar (not visible any more due to wiki post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [nxt_lxf2urdf tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt_lxf2urdf/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20simple%20robot%20model%20using%20lxf2urdf.py) explains how to convert your Lego digital designer files to URDF. That enables you to visualize your robot model in RViz. However, simulation in Gazebo is not possible at the moment (see [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/1071/is-there-already-a-lego-mindstorms-nxt-simulation)).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0